# Escape character issue

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error, batch-processing

I am getting below error for the syntax :

```
batch4.bat ('a00180000017agkAAA','a00180000017agkAAB')

Error: at marked point as
batch4.bat ('a00180000017agkAAA <here errors out>','a00180000017agkAAB')
```

Batch file code: batch4.bat

```
cls

set classpath="C:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Data Loader\dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar"
set mainclass=com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner
set confdir="C:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Bkp"

if [%1]==[]  goto error

call java -cp %classpath% -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%confdir% %mainclass% process.name=Product_vod__c 

sfdc.extractionSOQL="SELECT Id,name FROM Product_vod__c where Id in %1"
goto end

:error
echo Error: missing date argument (must be in 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ' format)
:end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: call java -cp %classpath% -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%confdir% %mainclass% process.name=Product_vod__c sfdc.extractionSOQL="SELECT Id,name FROM Product_vod__c where Id in %1"

Comment: Please find call statement having soql in complete string

Comment: Post the complete batch file and tell us how you invoke it because `%1` means the first command line parameter.

Comment: Place double-quotes around the entire argument, then extract it by `%~1` (the `~` modifier removes the quotes then).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your .bat file like this:

```
batch4.bat a00180000017agkAAA a00180000017agkAAB
```

Comment: No I need to place it in a string where it will be in a query. Please find the query statement here : sfdc.extractionSOQL="SELECT Id,name FROM Product_vod__c where Id in %1"